# Converting maxValue of DateTime to DateTime

Tags: c#

```
string date1 = "31.12.9999";
Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
```

if i run code above i always get error

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Is there a solution how to convert this DateTime?

Comment: The ToDateTime converter might expect another time format on the string!? Have you specified the culture?

Comment: what are your culture settings? actually this is a very robust method to convert strings to datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var date1 = "31.12.9999";
var dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Bobek if this one worked then this is definetely a duplicate